# Facebook graph API mark as spam and filter conversation

Tags: facebook-graph-api

In my messenger app, I need to block spams, and filter out when I call conversation list. Is this possible with graph API? How can I filter out the ones which are marked as spam?

```
`https://graph.facebook.com/${version}/${PAGE_ID}/conversations?${queryParam}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request the conversations from within a specific folder only, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/conversation/#folders

| Folder. | Description |
| --- | --- |
| inbox | Messages in your inbox |
| other |  |
| page_done | Messages marked as Done that are no longer in your Page's main inbox. These messages are no longer visible in your inbox. |
| pending | Messages in your pending folder |
| spam. | Messages marked as Spam. These messages are no longer visible in your inbox but have not been deleted. |

You can specify the folder name after conversations edge, i.e.
`https://graph.facebook.com/${version}/${PAGE_ID}/conversations/inbox`

I don't know if you can specify multiple folders at once though, should you need messages from more than one. A combination like `/conversations/other,inbox` still appears to give results, but I do not have enough data available to verify whether it's correct or not right now.